# Compaq CQ61-319WM will not boot from just AC; dead battery has to charge

Tags: boot, laptop, power-supply, battery

A friend gave me an old laptop to play around with, and it's exhibiting a peculiar symptom: it has to charge up the battery for a few minutes before it will turn on.  The battery does not have much life in it and ***you cannot run the laptop on just the AC adapter***.

I've never seen nor heard of a laptop that would not run with its battery removed; this is a standard troubleshooting step, even on HP's support site where people are making similar (but not the same) complaints for this family of laptop.  HP bought Compaq some time ago if you didn't know.

These laptops apparently had issues with their batteries, and I can find some on Amazon for less than $14, but I am still perplexed about what's going on with the laptop.  Once the battery has charged up enough, the laptop will boot and run just fine.  I've got it running Ubuntu.  I can't find anything else wrong with it, save the damaged USB port.

Thinking it was a BIOS setting, I looked through the BIOS menus and did not find much besides a boot order and to enable or disable virtual machine support.

What could make a laptop not boot from it's AC adapter only and require a battery?

**Edit**

The laptop lets you know if it's ready to boot or not.  If it's not ready, the charge LED will blink.  If it is ready, the charge LED will remain solid.  There is a period of overlap where the charge LED is solid but the laptop will not boot.  The process of getting the battery ready takes 5 - 20 minutes.